# Pyexcel Save to a Dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to import a simple xls file and add the data to a Dictionary. I can add them to a list fine. The problem is the Dictionary.

```
import pyexcel
import pyexcel.ext.xls
book = pyexcel.get_book(file_name="Test.xls")# The external file
names =  {}

names[book["Test"].column[5]] = [book["Sheet1"].column[0]]#Adding the data to the dictionary
```

Below is the error code:

```
names[book["Test"].column[5]] = [book["Sheet1"].column[0]]
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Comment: You can't use a list as a dictionary key. `.column` returns a list. You'll have to find something else to use as a key.

Comment: I have tried ' '.join() to no avail

Comment: Add that to your post. The exact code you tried and the exact error message.

Comment: Apologies forgot to put it on the key also. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use Pyexcel, so my answer is based on creating a dictionary from 2 lists. if `.column[5]` is a list of keys and `.column[0]` is the list of values then to create a dictionary called names:

```
names = dict(zip(book["Test"].column[5], book["Sheet1"].column[0]))
```

Here's the principle expressed in a simple example:

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c']

b = [1,2,3]

dict(zip(a, b))
Out[3]: {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
```

Comment: The zip method is a much cleaner way. However it seems to only allow me one value to a key.

Comment: That's generally how a dict works. It would be helpful then to provide an example of what .column[5] and .column[0] returns and how you want to see those values in the dict.

Answer (score 0):

I have the answer for this. It seems a bit messy but works well.

```
import pyexcel
import pyexcel.ext.xls
book = pyexcel.get_book(file_name="Test.xls")
names =  {}
a = ' , '.join(book["Test"].column[3])
b = a.split(',')



c = ' ,'.join(book["Test"].column[0])
d = c.split(',')

for index, (value1, value2) in enumerate(zip(d, b)):
     names[value1] = value2
print(names)
```

Comment: a = ' , '.join(book["Test"].column[3])
b = a.split(',') can be replaced with book['test'].column.format(3,str)